# "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )" syntax error

Tags: java, android, regex

I wrote code for matching filepath which have extenstion .ncx ,

```
 pattern = Pattern.compile("$(\\|\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_]/.ncx");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.mather("\sample.ncx");
```

This shows a invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ ) syntax error pattern. How can I fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[/\\\\]([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.ncx)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\\sample.ncx");
if (m.find())
{
  System.out.printf("The filename is '%s'%n", m.group(1));
}
```

output:

```
The filename is 'sample.ncx'
```

---

`$` [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the match to the end of the string (or to the end of a line in multiline mode).  It belongs at the *end* of your regex, not the beginning.

`[/\\\\]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches a forward-slash or a backslash.  The backslash has to be double-escaped because it has special meaning both in a regex and in a string literal.  The forward-slash does *not* require escaping.

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` matches **one or more** of the listed characters; without the [plus sign](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), you were only matching *one*.

The second forward-slash in your regex makes no sense, but you do need a backslash there to escape the [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)--and of course, the backslash has to be escaped for the Java string literal.

Because I switched from the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`) to a character class for the leading slash, the parentheses in your regex were no longer needed.  Instead, I used them to [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the actual filename, just to demonstrate how that's done.

Answer (score 5):

In java `\` is a reserved character for escaping. so you need to escape the `\`.

```
pattern=Pattern.compile("$(\\\\|\\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_]/.ncx");
```

Comment: That should probably be `$(\\\\|\\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_]/.ncx` The first '\' needs to be escaped too.

Comment: @tim Thx. updated. The question was edited after i posted my answer (org question only had 1 \\).

Comment: @The Scrum Meister Thanks for the quick reply.but it is not matched with a/f/sample.ncx ???

Comment: @kariyachan What are you trying to accomplish? There are multiple things wrong with your regex, `$` = end of string, the `.` is not escaped... Please read a Regex tutorial.

Comment: Okay,To get the String that ended with .ncx extenstion

Comment: @kariyachan Do you want the filename or the entire path?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(\\|\\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_]/.ncx
```

Comment: was editing. : ) knew that people will answer quickly. he is looking for OS independent file path I guess.